# Webstorm with CreateJS library

Tags: javascript, html, web, webstorm, createjs

Can you show me how to add custom JS library(CreateJS in this case) in webstorm and use the intellisense/code auto complete for it. I tried myself, in file->settings->javascript->libraries I clicked add and in the Edit Library pop-up window I specified the url,in this case http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.12.12.min.js. But the auto complete code isn't working. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm doesn't use external javascript files available via CDN links for completion - you need to have the file available on your local disk. When it's done, you can use the file chooser in Edit Library to select the file(s) and attach it to the library
Note that you can use 'Download library' intention to download and install libraries from http. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/javascript-libraries.html#d50107e417 for details